# Help Me Identify My Bike Serial No. : HZ100202418

Tags: identify-this-bike

Hi please help me identify my bicycle, which has serial number HZ100202418.

[image]

Here's a picture of the head-tube badge, but I don't think it's original

[image: BADGE]

Comment: what does the badge at the front say?

Comment: The serial number is almost certainly no use but that's a distinctive-looking frame, which should help. Please also give us a photo of the badge on the head tube, which is the most obvious identifying feature on almost any bike.

Comment: I think the badge is just and add on and not original.

Comment: The badge I think was just glued on.

Comment: The top tubes looks like a 20's Hawthorne, but other parts (geometry, seatpost collar) do not match. Maybe a modern-ish replica.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** its a modern bike inspired by workman bikes of the 1950s.

---

Mayam is/was a bicycle company in Nagoya Japan, and was related to "Nittei Industry Co"  They were known for their "heavy duty carrier bicycles" which is where the double top-tube comes from.

[image: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51pzSN8XS-L.jpg] 1970s advert.

[image: http://chikutakurinrin.cocolog-nifty.com/photos/uncategorized/2011/01/10/img_8454.jpg]
Older advert reproduced in a calendar.

[image: http://chikutakurinrin.cocolog-nifty.com/photos/uncategorized/2011/08/07/img_1975.jpg] Japanese "Guarantee Medal"  associating the names Mayam and Nittei

More info  http://chikutakurinrin.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2011/08/index.html

---

Your bike appears to be a modern reproduction "inspired-by" the older models.  Reasons:

- The fork has nowhere near as much rake as the old bikes.
- Dual pivot front rim brake
- No rear brake - loaded bikes take some stopping, though a coaster brake might work.
- No carrier, nor lugs to fit a carrier
- No mudguard mounts either.  A workman's bike gets used in the rain and wet.
- Super short head tube.  Back then head tubes were longer - short ones increased stresses on the head tube/top/downtube weld areas.  Also related to load carrying limits
- Deeper section wheels - these bikes would have had steel box section rims for strength while carrying loads.

Other - Not sure whats up with that bottle cage - might be some special modern thing that interfaces with a special bottle.